How come some VSCode windows are in a different color?
When I connect to a specific host in VSCode, the color of the window always changes to this color. It doesn't seem to happen when using VSCode normally, nor with any other host.

How does this work? I'm interested in configuring it and making it happen for certain other hosts too. I looked in user settings JSON but didn't seem to spot anything.
I don't have the Color Windows extension installed.
